# NodeMCU disconnects and ADC not found

Tags: nodemcu, adc

I had a working Wi-Fi NodeMCU compiled code with community version 2.4.2 but wanted to add the ESP32 ADC functionality per the "See the documentation" document and used p0Val = adc.read(0); but I got 
"'adc' was not declared in this scope. In attempting to get it to work I upgraded from version 2.4.2 to 2.7.0(the latest) and it still is not recognized. Is there a special .h file that I need for ADC functionality?
After upgrading to 2.7.0 my NodeMCU station immediately disconnects from the client. Ran debug Wi-Fi and here is the output:

```
enter code here
```

scandone

[WIFI] scan done

[WIFI] 5 networks found

--->  0: [6][BC:64:4B:A8:90:8D] WIFI21FA52 (-66) *

```
   1: [1][08:D5:9D:92:52:C6] MySpectrumWiFic0-2G (-88) *

   2: [1][58:90:43:0D:91:9E] MySpectrumWiFi98-2G (-93) *

   3: [6][02:20:00:35:D1:CF] DIRECT-iaLexmark MC2425adw-cfd1 (-58) *
   4: [6][D8:A7:56:75:BE:4E] MySpectrumWiFi48-2G (-85) *
```

[WIFI] Connecting BSSID: BC:64:4B:A8:90:8D SSID: WIFI21FA52 Channel: 6 (-66)

scandone

state: 0 -> 2 (b0)

state: 2 -> 0 (2)

reconnect

wifi evt: 1

This continues forever and the debug doesn't tell me anything that gives me clue what's happening. Why is my original code now not working under version 2.7.0?

Comment: [WIFI] Connecting BSSID: BC:64:4B:A8:90:8D SSID: WIFI21FA52 Channel: 11 (-59)
scandone
state: 0 -> 2 (b0)
state: 2 -> 3 (0)
state: 3 -> 5 (10)
add 0
aid 5
cnt 

connected with WIFI21FA52, channel 11
dhcp client start...
wifi evt: 0
wifi evt: 7
wifi evt: 7
wifi evt: 7
wifi evt: 7
[WIFI] Connecting Failed (6).
.[WIFI] delete old wifi config...
state: 5 -> 0 (0)
rm 0
[WIFI] start scan
wifi evt: 1
STA disconnect: 8

Answer (score 0):

The connection problem > This works for STAtion: WiFi.begin("network-name", "pass-to-network");
This fails: wifiMulti Something happened between ver 2.4.2 and 2.7.0 because the code for wifiMulti is right out of readthedoc.io
The ADC problem > readthedoc.io has: val = adc.read(0)
arduino core has: val = analogRead(A0) This works: Provides the analog counts(0-1024): p0Val = analogRead(A0); Serial.printf("Analog Counts = [%04u]",p0Val);